# NodeJS: How to create an only outbound email delivery system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, koa, koa2

How can I create a system that is used ONLY for outbound email delivery from a non-existent email address such as (no-reply@fakedomain.com)? This system need not receive any emails.

I read [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/) is used for this but in my experience it requires the outbound email address to be configured and authenticated. However, it is a non-existent email hence, I can not authenticate or configure it. Hence, in my experience this doesnt work. Please correct me if I am wrong and guide me to correctly implement this.

Comment: One option is to use a real email address and just set up that mailbox to auto-delete any incoming email and perhaps configure an auto-responder to inform anyone sending email that nobody is reading this email.  Outbound email these days is often checked for authenticity (in the never ending fight against spam) so the mailbox may need to exist in order to pass those checks unless you have a customized email server.

Comment: It is generally bad idea to ask for something that has no plausible legitimate use... There are likely special sites that welcome spam-mailers development, SO is not one of them. But even if it would be you still need to present *programming* question and not request to explain mail protocols and security around them.

Comment: I am sorry if this question presented as a spam mail generator. However this is for uses such as notifications, invites, password resets, and one way communications.For these, you do not need to have an existing email address

Comment: @TempO'rary - Unless you want to customize an outbound SMTP server or configure and run your own SMTP server that supports sending from a non-existent mailbox, you will need to have an actual mailbox behind the scenes in order to properly send from that mailbox.  It costs nothing to have an actual mailbox there as long as you just configure it to not accept email or to automatically delete it when it does arrive.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Node, or Koa. And `nodemailer` *only* sends mail. It doesn't act as a POP3 or IMAP client. Your question is really about how to configure your MTA (Mail Transport Agent) so that it refuses or discards incoming mail.